# Sum of the values of a particular user for a particular month of a particular year

Tags: laravel

I have a table with ***time stamp, user id, value***. I am trying to get sum of the values of a particular user for a particular month of a particular year. This is what I am using:

```
$data = Laborhrs::all()->where('employee','7')->sum('value');
```

This is giving me sum of whole data for employee#7. I am looking to get sum of a particular month of a particular year. Say Sum of values of October 2018. What am I missing?

Comment: employee is timestamp column ?

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, but important nonetheless: `all()` method will issue a query to DB and return you a collection. So your `where(...)` call goes on the **collection** object and it's not the best practice - it's much more efficient to delegate it to your DB side. Same goes for aggregating functions (such as `sum(...)` in your example since it's also featured in query builder object). Selecting everything from DB and only then operating on collection of objects is very bad and can drastically slow your script execution time while also increasing memory consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a condition for the year and month, and you don't need to use `all()` method.

```
$sum = Laborhrs::where('employee','7')
        ->whereMonth('timestamp_column_name', 10)
        ->whereYear('timestamp_column_name', 2018)
        ->sum('value');
```

In addition: I saw your several posts, and I think, you don't understand how laravel eloquent and collections work.

`All()` method returns collection with all results from database, and then you filters them trough collection (I saw it not first time). It is very slow solution.

Better to use conditions with `get()` (`get()` should go after conditions), for example:

```
$data = Laborhrs::where('employee','7')->get();
```

It will return collection with results that you need, and you don't need to filter them after getting from database. It will be work much faster.

In that situtation you don't need `all()` and `get()`  methods at all. Eloquent has `sum()` method, that will calculate sum in database and return value.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation. I have noted your input and trying to understand it.